# How to dynamically change the values of MAUI OnPlatform resources?

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui

I understood how to change `Color` below in C#.

```
<Color x:Key="TextColor">Yellow</Color>

Resources["TextColor"] = Colors.Blue;
```

But I don't know how to change, for example Android's value below in C#.

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="FontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="20"/>
    <On Platform="WinUI" Value="80"/>
</OnPlatform>
```

Comment: Do you want to have a `DynamicResource` for `FontSize` which has an `OnPlatform` usage?

Comment: Do checkout my maui controls here : https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you need to do is reassign the value to the Resource.

So below:

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="FontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
<On Platform="Android" Value="20"/>
<On Platform="WinUI" Value="80"/>
</OnPlatform>
```

Can be updated like:

```
 Resources["FontSize"] = GetFontSize();

   private int GetFontSize()
   {
    if (Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
    {
        return 20;
    }
    else if (Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.WinUI)
    {
        return 20;
    }
    else
    {
        return 80;
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demo for you and it worked well. You can refer to this.

```
<Button Margin="0,10,0,0"  Text="Learn more"
        Command="{Binding OpenWebCommand}"
        TextColor="White">
    <Button.BackgroundColor>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Green"/>
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Orange"/>
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Purple"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Button.BackgroundColor>
</Button>
```

For more information, you can read this [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#onplatform-markup-extension).

Comment: What is that? How do you change `Green` in c#? It is an out of topic answer.